# При построении гистограммы вместо дистибуции получаю количество записей

Tags: python, pandas

У меня есть DataFrame.

Вот пример:

```
                                      s
           time 
2017-01-03 09:30:00.083000-05:00    17323.0
2017-01-03 09:30:00.505000-05:00    66.0
2017-01-03 09:30:05.469000-05:00    300.0
2017-01-03 09:30:08.555000-05:00    100.0
2017-01-03 09:30:10.927000-05:00    114.0
2017-01-03 09:30:12.279000-05:00    99.0
2017-01-03 09:30:28.225000-05:00    19.0
2017-01-03 09:30:32.511000-05:00    15.0
2017-01-03 09:30:40.899000-05:00    200.0
2017-01-03 09:30:40.925000-05:00    327.0
```

Строю обычную гистограмму:

```
data_2['s'].hist();
```

Вот результат:

[image: Результат]

Я хочу получить что-то вроде вот такого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему вместо дистибуции получаю количество записей? Как исправить эту ошибку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все правильно! По умолчанию значения разбиваются на 10 равных интервалов. Для приведенных в вопросе данных все значения кроме первой строки попадают в первый интервал (со значениями < 1730):

```
In [41]: df["s"].hist()
Out[41]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x2003119b4e0>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

границы интервалов можно задать самостоятельно:

```
In [46]: df["s"].hist(bins=[0, 100, 200, 300, 500])
Out[46]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x2003503cf60>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]